# how to define a function to arrange words in alphabetical order

Tags: python-2.7, anagram

I am new to python and trying to write a program to check whether two words are anagram to each other. However, I don't want to use builtin functions such as `sort()` or `sorted()`. I want to do it through my own function but I am not able to do it. My code does not work properly.

```
a=raw_input("Enter a string: ")
b=raw_input("Enter another string: ")


def arrange(x):
   """To arrange strings alphabetically charecter wise"""
   c=list(x)
   f=""
   for i in range(65,90,1):
        for j in c:

            if j == unichr(i) :
                f=f+j
            else :
                print "not ok"
   print "f=",f                
   return f



e = arrange(b)
d = arrange(a)
if d==e :
    print "anagram"
else :
    print "not anagram"
```

Comment: You look like you are on the right track. However, it's a little unclear what is wrong with your code. Can you explain a little more about what the issue is? Thanks!

Comment: Your function appears to be indented incorrectly, can you fix the code so it looks like it does in your file?

Comment: Blue Ice please tell me what kind of explanation you want ... i mean regarding the outputs or the logic or something else, etc. Thank you!

Comment: @11_Samy_98 I'm looking for an explanation of what output you are getting and why it is not correct. :)